# Installing package in python virtual environment using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QJGJ.png)

Using CMD I can install any package in virtual environment but when I do the same thing using Jupyter Notebook. It says
c:\users\puneet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Add `!` infront of it, it will execute it as a command in cmd

```
!pip install matplotlib
```

If it didn't work, it might be installing the current version in the `$PATH` variable of the OS, and not the Jupyter version.

Try this if you are on Jupyter 7.3 or later

```
%pip install matplotlib
```

otherwise try

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me ( Installing collected packages: matplotlib
Successfully installed matplotlib-3.4.3 ) but now when I use matplotlib ( like : from matplotlib import pyplot as plt ), it again says ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' )

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if it worked

Comment: If I use ( import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install matplotlib ) it again says the same previous error like ( 'c:\users\puneet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. )

Comment: try `%pip intall matplotlib`? only works on 7.3 or later

Comment: same previous error  **'c:\users\puneet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**  Note: I'm using virtual Environment.

Comment: and if I run `!pip list` it shows `matplotlib      3.4.3`

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the pip command on the shell from jupyter notebook environment. For that you need to use `!` before the command.
For example, try out `!ls` inside jupyter notebook.
You'll see that it lists out the files and folders in the current directory.

Now, to install your desired module, simply use

```
!pip install <module name>
```

Comment: Module is successfully installed but still when I use it like ( from matplotlib import pyplot as plt ) it says ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
 )

Comment: it would be 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`